# iPhone facebook app - when opeing a link in the facebook app, safari rules being ignored - why?

Tags: iphone, facebook, mobile, safari

im using some js to insert safari specific styles on a website im making. when i open the site in mobile safari on an iphone, the styles work fine.

but for some reason, when i post a link to the site on facebook, and then through my facebook app open the link, the styles are ignored - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean in the internal web frame of Facebook before you click 'Open This Link in Safari' then it's because it's not Safari, it's just a stock and standard Web View with no access to any of the other Safari features (that's why it's often quicker to open the link in Safari).

EDIT:
I decided to dig a bit further (this has probably been done before but I didn't find it on the first page of Google so). I have a site with practically zero traffic so I used that, monitored through Google Analytics to see what my browser agent would come back as. The only device connect was my iPhone at that point and it sends the browser agent as 'Mozilla Compatible Agent' for Browser, with iPhone as the OS. I then logged on through Safari and checked again.

Looks like for the UIWebView Apple decided not to bother putting the Safari user agent, which is weird. Or weirdish, I suppose it has a lot less functionality so not showing it as a stock agent might be a good thing.

Picture: 
[image: the two agents under Analytics]

Comment: genius! thank you - is there any way to target this browser with specific styles?

Comment: I'd imagine so but I can't think how to do it. For the most part it should send that it is mobile Safari running with <x> but it has limited access to the javascript engine which could be throwing your js off.

Comment: Well I'll be, I'll update my answer for you. TL;DR iOS does something weird with sending Browser Agent.

Comment: thanks for the great investigative response.  this is a bit of a pain, but Im sure ill find a common ground solution rather than relying so heavily on browser detection.